# Eclipse Class File Error - localPlayerList

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Why localPlayerList gaves me an error? Thank You (my error is signed with **localPlayerList**

```
public OfflinePlayer findPlayer(String paramString)
{
    Object localObject = this.plugin.getServer().getOfflinePlayer(paramString);
    if(!((OfflinePlayer) localObject).hasPlayedBefore())
    {
        localObject = this.plugin.getServer().getPlayer(paramString);
    }
    if(localObject == null)
    {
        PlayerList localPlayerList = this.plugin.getPlayerList(true);
        for(PlayerList.Entry localEntry : localPlayerList)
        {
            String str = paramString.toLowerCase();
            if(localEntry.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(str))
            {
                localObject = this.plugin.getServer().getOfflinePlayer(localEntry.name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (OfflinePlayer) localObject;
}
```

Comment: What error do you mean? This is just code.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the `PlayerList.Entry` mentioned in the `for` loop, `PlayerList` probably implements [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which means to iterate around the entries it should be called like this:

```
for(PlayerList.Entry localEntry : localPlayerList.entrySet())
```